# Clicks "restart" in RDP -> Brings back to my local PC -> I don't know when the RDP will fully wake up -> Whenever it's wake up it login automatically

Tags: remote-desktop, shell-script, windows-server-2012, auto-login

I have 2 programs in the RDP -- 1)A.bat & 2)B.exe

Execution process of A.bat is something like -

> **Step1: Download a file from internet using the command --**

```
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://laptop-updates.brave.com/latest/winx64' -OutFile 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\B.exe'"
```

> **Step2: Modify a RegistryKey so that B.exe can run automatically in the**
> **next reboot. Command used for that purpose--**

```
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v runonce /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\B.exe" /f
```

> **Step3(Last step): Reboots the RDP. Command used--**

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Execution process of B.exe is not our concern. My problem is when A.bat executes the last command the RDP session closes and returns me to my local pc. RDP takes some time to fully wake up. After waking up it doesn't automatically login to it's desktop. Again i have to login manually to the RDP using Remote Desktop Connection so that B.exe can run. I just want that after reboot, RDP automatically login to the desktop causing B.exe to run in the startup.

### N.B: **Using Windows Server 2019 in Amazon EC2 instance as RDP.**

Answer (score 1):

RDP will not login automatically just because the server on the other side
has rebooted. The most you can do is write a script that you can run
on your side to do the logon, so as to make it easier to start the
remote session.

You may save in RDP the connection details to a `.rdp` file,
specifying fully the parameters for the connection, window size,
shared devices and more.

To launch the `.rdp` file, use the
[mstsc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)
command:

```
mstsc path\connection-file.rdp
```

You may put the command in a `.bat` file, or as a desktop icon,
to restart the remote session with one double-click.

Comment: Not entirely true. Usually the script just starts an application. If you turn that application into a service, you do not even need to login. That is the preferred way to solve this problem.

Comment: @LPChip: The system service is already there - this is Terminal Services. The problem is to start a session.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are not understanding my comment here. They are doing something that makes them need to start b.exe. If they turn b.exe into a service with auto-start enabled, they can just reboot without even logging in and it will work.

Comment: @LPChip: Right, I misunderstood. However, that won't help unless he can avoid the reboot.

Comment: No, if you setup the b.exe as service then you can freely reboot. We do it all the time for our clients where possible. We do not want auto-login into servers just to start something up because that puts the login into the register for any hacker to find.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what b.exe is, it is hard to suggest the proper strategy here.

But that said, when a remote server reboots, RDP will obviously always disconnect. There is nothing you can do, and given that boot times are different, there is no easy way to automatically reconnect after the connection is ready again.

That said, it is usually not the right approach to want to login to a server just so a program can start.

The right way to do it, is turn that program into a service, such that if the server reboots, the server just starts automatically and no one even needs to be logged in.

There are different programs (free) out there that can turn any program into a service. Process Hacker 2 (taskmanager replacement) is one of them, but there are more. I believe Microsoft's SysInternals have a program that can do it too.

So, if you want B.exe to always run after startup, turn it into a service. You can even create a service from the command prompt. The only requirement for a service is, that you are working with a .exe file, but that is what you have.